# Metric $p := p(x,y)= \min(|x-y|, 1- |x-y|)$ $x,y \in [0,1)^2$. Prove metric space is compact.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

Help! I know that $X$ is Compact if every sequence in $X$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $X$. 
Also we have that $X$ is a bounded infinite subset in the real numbers.

I think it's quite a short proof, could anyone help please? 
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but surely the limit point 1 does not belong to the set, which it must in order to be compact?

Comment: The sequence $\{(1-1/n,0)\}$ tends towards $(1,0)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ in its usual topology; but that's not relevant to what it converges to in $X$ in this topology. In fact, it converges perfectly nicely to $(0,0)$ in $X$.

Comment: My mistake.Okay then to prove the problem it is sufficient to show that any sequence converging to points that contain a coordinate with 1 converges to 0. So in other words if you have a sequence that converge to $(1,a)$ under the standard metric, show that it converges to $(0,a)$ in your new metric. And similarly show that any sequence converging to $(a,1)$ converges in the standard metric converges to $(a,0)$. And you are done. Where $a\in [0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=[0,1)$ with the given metric, and let $Y=[0,1]$ with the usual metric.

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in X, then it has a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which converges to $a \in Y$ since Y is compact.

1) If $a\ne1$, then $x_{n_k}$ converges to $a$ in X since

$\;\;\;|x_{n_k}-a|<\epsilon\implies d(x_{n_k},a)=\min\{|x_{n_k}-a|, 1-|x_{n_k}-a|\}<\epsilon$.

2) If $a=1$, then $x_{n_k}$ converges to 0 in X since

$\;\;\;|x_{n_k}-1|<\epsilon\implies 1-x_{n_k}<\epsilon\implies d(x_{n_k},0)=\min\{x_{n_k},1-x_{n_k}\}<\epsilon$.

Therefore $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence in X, so X is compact.